# Any successful website built on top of Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web

I would like to know whether there are any websites (not toy projects) that have been successfully built on top of GAE (excluding google) using whatever programming languages or frameworks that are available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course there are. We've featured a few of them on [the blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/) in the past, including [webfilings](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/08/webfilings-streamlines-sec-reporting.html), [Wolfire games](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-app-engine-served-humble-indie.html), and [Neptune's Pride](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/04/games-on-app-engine-interview-with-jay.html), to name a few.

Answer (score 3):

[Overgrowth](http://www.wolfire.com/overgrowth) looks fairly big.

The [App Engine gallery](http://appgallery.appspot.com/), but it has been closed.

And there is also [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)...

See: [5 cool web applications hosted on Google App Engine](http://www.programmerfish.com/five-cool-apps-hosted-on-google-app-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

[Snapchat](http://www.snapchat.com/) uses Google App Engine. They just turned down a $3 Billion offer I believe, so they are very successful in that sense. Source: [Gigaom Article](http://gigaom.com/2013/05/07/snapchats-act-of-faith-in-building-on-google-compute-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

[WordsKeeper](https://words-keeper.com) - web application for foreign language learners.